# How to fetch integer value from given string? 

Tags: c#, java, android

I want to find integer value from a string. For example, given a String like "Ahmedabad to Gandhinagar Distance:29km(about 31 mins)"

I want to fetch only 29 from the given String because i want to compare this 29 kilometers to other kilometers.

Comment: Which language are you using? You specify both C# and Java. Is the string from which you're extracting the value regular - is it always in the same format? If so, you could find the ':' and extract the digits that follow it.

Comment: What is the language you want this answer for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, you can use a Regex.Match to pull out substrings if you use groups in the regex (note this is not tested...).  There is probably a similar mechanism in Java, but I don't know it off the top of my head:

```
var myString = @"Ahmedabad to Gandhinagar Distance:29km(about 31 mins)";
var myRegex = @".*:(\d*)km.*";
var match = Regex.Match(myString, myRegex);

if (match.Success)
{
    // match.Groups contains the match "groups" in the regex (things surrounded by parentheses)
    // match.Groups[0] is the entire match, and in this case match.Groups[1] is the km value
    var km = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex

```
/[:](\d+)/
```

and you'll have the match as 29. Here is a [rubular link](http://www.rubular.com/r/wWIV2oa6eW) with your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in C#

```
            string str = "Ahmedabad to Gandhinagar Distance:29km(about 31 mins)";
            str = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(':')+1, str.IndexOf("km") - str.IndexOf(':')-1); ;
            int distance = Convert.ToInt32(str);
```